# how to avoid root elevation dialog using SCNetworkInterfaceForceConfigurationRefresh in MAC 10.11

Tags: macos, networking, xcode, configuration

Our App tries to perform DHCP refresh without popping up for elevating user credential.
We have seen the SCNetworkConfiguration api has some functions to achive this.

in the apple developer site .
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Networking/Reference/SCNetworkConfiguration/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/SCNetworkInterfaceForceConfigurationRefresh

we have implented a sample application with SCNetworkInterfaceForceConfigurationRefresh()

whenever we runs this code, it is popping up for user credential from MAC 10.11.
Can anybody help us how to go about this issue that "the user wont be asked for credential whenever the dhcp refresh happens".

Here is our sample code:

```
            AuthorizationRef auth=NULL;
            AuthorizationFlags flags= kAuthorizationFlagDefaults | kAuthorizationFlagInteractionAllowed |
                                    kAuthorizationFlagPreAuthorize | kAuthorizationFlagExtendRights;
            AuthorizationCreate(NULL, kAuthorizationEmptyEnvironment, flags,&auth);
            SCPreferencesRef prefs=SCPreferencesCreateWithAuthorization(NULL, CFSTR("sample"), NULL, auth);
            SCPreferencesLock(prefs, TRUE);
            SCNetworkSetRef networkset = SCNetworkSetCopyCurrent(prefs);
            NSLog(@"%@",networkset);
            NSArray *services=(__bridge_transfer NSArray *)(SCNetworkSetCopyServices(networkset));
            for(id networkService_ in services)
            {
                SCNetworkServiceRef networkservice=(__bridge SCNetworkServiceRef)networkService_;
                SCNetworkInterfaceRef interface=SCNetworkServiceGetInterface(networkservice);
                NSLog(@"%@",interface);
                bool i=SCNetworkInterfaceForceConfigurationRefresh(interface);
                NSLog(@"%d",i);
            }
            SCPreferencesUnlock(prefs);
```

Comment: Surely if something affects all users rather than just the user running it needs to have raised privileges otherwise you could be writing a key logger or other virus. i.e. If there is a way to do this isn't it a security hole?

Comment: Yeah you are right this would be a change for all users, it is calling DHCP IP address refresh, thats all. It is not a keylogger or virus

Comment: My point is that if you can do this so can a key logger - how do you differentiate?